# Can I override the standard emoji styles (the way they look) on the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, unicode, emoji

I have a project which uses emojis.

Users will interact with it on the browser, but they will eventually copy and paste it to whatsapp.

So I would like them to see emojis with the Whatsapp styles, rather than seeing one thing and then see it change to a different style once they paste it to Whatsapp.

Is there a way to override how the styles for the emojis on the browser?

Example: this is how it looks on Chrome [image]

This is how it looks on Whatsapp [image]

The size difference is because I've zoomed in, but this literally the same emoji copied and pasted from/to whatsapp-web and browser.

Is it possible to build a text input the make the emojis look like their Whatsapp version?

```css
.arialDiv {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.timesDiv {
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
}

.otherDiv {
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<div class="arialDiv">
<input class="arialDiv" type="text" value=" Arial"/>
</div>
<div class="timesDiv">
<input class="timesDiv" type="text" value=" Times new roman"/>
</div>
<div class="otherDiv">
<input class="otherDiv" type="text" value=" Helvetica"/>
</div>
```

[image]

It seems they use Helvetic Neue by Linotype.

https://www.fontmirror.com/helvetica-neue

[image]

But the regular font file does not come with the emojis.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just use the same font as WhatsApp does? Emoji are just text, and their display style depends simply on what font is picked.

Comment: If I change the font-family I will change the way emojis are rendered? Is this how it works? I could definetely use their font.

Comment: Emoji are text, yes. Their look depends entirely on the font.

Comment: However, WhatsApp uses [image sprites](https://web.whatsapp.com/img/emoji-25-20_049836a.webp) to display their emojis in Chrome. This way, they ensure the same style is applied anywhere, no matter the font

Comment: @TRiG see the snippet that I've added. I don't think fonts control the way emojis look. I don't remember ever seeing a web font's file containing a sprite sheet for emojis or something. Are you sure this is how it works? It seems more like it's a browser/operating system level kind of thing. Thanks!

Comment: @blex yes! I've also saw that when I inspected whatsapp web on chrome. I saw the spritesheet. So basically if I want their style I will have to implement my own emoji rendering system, to replace emojis with `<img>` or some other elment with the `background-image` pointing to a spritesheet with their styles? So this is basically impossible to do using a regular `<input>` element. Right?

Comment: They're part of Unicode, ergo they are text. Now, if a web page contains a character which isn't in the given font, browsers will fall back to another font and pull the character from there. So if none of those fonts actually have emoji (not many fonts have good emoji support), the browser will pull from some other font, possibly the same font in all three cases, which would explain why they look the same. Do we know what font WhatsApp uses? Can it be licensed?

Comment: Apparently, [WhatsApp uses its own font](https://emojipedia.org/whatsapp/), and using copyrighted emojis could [potentially be illegal](https://www.howtogeek.com/293831/are-emoji-copyrighted/)... However, I didn't find whether or not WhatsApp's emojis were actually copyrighted or not. But it's owned by Facebook, so the chances are big

Comment: @blex take a look at this package: https://github.com/missive/emoji-mart they offer many sets of emojis, including facebook's. 3.1k Github stars. Doesn't mention anything copyrights, though.

Comment: @cbdeveloper I looked it up, digged further, and found this mention "Apple images are not licensed for commercial usage. Android/Google/Noto emoji are available under the Apache License 2.0. Twitter emoji are available under the Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 license. **Facebook emoji have no clear licensing**." [here in the emoji source they used](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoji-datasource-facebook#image-sources). But that looks like a good starting point :)

Comment: @blex thanks! I think this package will work for what I need.